# What is wrong with this implementation of Producer Consumer in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have implemented the classic producer/consumer problem, using a shared buffer class.

For some reason I am not getting the correct sequence of outputs.

I have tried so many times, but could not spot the flaw, can someone please point out the mistake?

```
public class BufferProdCons {

    boolean produced = false;

    int data;

    public synchronized void produceData(int d) {

        while (produced) {

            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    //  System.out.println("data produced");
        data = d;
        produced = true;
        this.notify();
    }

    public synchronized int consumeData() {
        while (!produced) {

            try {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    //  System.out.println("data consumed");
        int d =data;
        produced = false;
        this.notify();
        return d;
    }
}

public class Consumer extends Thread {

    BufferProdCons buffer ;
    Consumer(BufferProdCons buf){
        buffer =  buf;
    }


    public void run(){
        for (int i =0;i<10;i++){
            int d=buffer.consumeData();
            System.out.println("Consumed data "+d);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}

public class Producer extends Thread {

    BufferProdCons buffer;

    Producer(BufferProdCons buf){
        buffer = buf;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            System.out.println("Produced "+i);
            buffer.produceData(i);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MainProdCons {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        BufferProdCons  buffer = new BufferProdCons();

        Thread t1 = new Producer(buffer);
        Thread t2 = new Consumer(buffer);

        t1.start();t2.start();
    }

}
```

---

### sample Output

```
Produced 0
Consumed data 0
Produced 1
Consumed data 1
Produced 2
Produced 3
Consumed data 2
Produced 4
Consumed data 3
Produced 5
Consumed data 4
Produced 6
Consumed data 5
Produced 7
Consumed data 6
Produced 8
Consumed data 7
Produced 9
Consumed data 8
Consumed data 9
```

---

My understanding is that , the sequence of producer and consumer lines should be alternate, But as you can see sometimes they appear in succession.

Comment: Could you add what "sequence of outputs" do you expect and what "sequence" you are getting?

Comment: Don't ever `extends Thread`. It's hugely error prone. When you use `synchronized` you will `synchronized(this)` and when `this` is a `Thread` you get some very odd behaviour. Never `extends Thread` and never lock on a `Thread` object unless you really know what you are doing.

Comment: One sample produces below output. and it varies from run to run
------------------
Produced 0
Consumed data 0
Produced 1
Consumed data 1
Produced 2
Produced 3
Consumed data 2
Produced 4
Consumed data 3
Produced 5
Consumed data 4
Produced 6
Consumed data 5
Produced 7
Consumed data 6
Produced 8
Consumed data 7
Produced 9
Consumed data 8
Consumed data 9
--------------
As you can see they are not printing alternately.

Comment: @BoristheSpider , Thanks , point duly noted, I will try with runnable, but just wanted to see it working,

Comment: Your question is still not clear at all. Show small example with output you are getting against output you expect.

Comment: @user3360241 Please read the above comment. Expectation is , that i should i get the sequence of producer and consumer alternately, but some times they appear in succession

Comment: Downvoters, Please explain, What is lacking in research here?

Comment: i haven't downvote you, but my guess it that you are getting down-voted based on poor definition of problem you are facing. Suggestion: edit question itself so that it is clear what you are asking, without reading comments.

Comment: It's probably a combination of different sleep intervals in your prod and consumer, and that there's never any guarantee of proper interleaving of console output with such tight intervals. I set your sleep intervals to 10 in both producer and consumer and got the output you expect....alternating produced/consumed messages

Comment: @swingMan , I have deliberately set the sleep interval of producer lower than consumer, so as to illustrate,(if my producer consumer is right then) consumer should not run before producer has produced. Although i have tried it even without sleep statements, i am getting similar output.

Comment: What might be happening, is that the out.write commands are being buffered. You could try your experiment again, but now with output flushing.

Comment: The output looks perfect, I don't know what the issue you are having it at all. Things are produced in sequence and consumed in sequence.

Comment: move `System.out.println` log messages into the synchronized  methods.